# activerecord - order by two associations from the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Currently I have in my model:

```
class RoutePair < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :flying_airline, class_name: 'Airline'
  belongs_to :home_airline, class_name: 'Airline'
end
```

I'm trying to write a query that orders them first by flying airline name, then followed by home airline name. My expected result will look like the following order:

```
AirAsia Air Hong Kong
AirAsia Eastern Air Lines
AirAsia Cebu Pacific
Cebu Pacific Air Hong Kong
Cebu Pacific AirAsia
Cebu Pacific Eastern Air Lines
```

Currently I can only order by flying_airline.

```
RoutePair.joins(:flying_airline, :home_airline).order('airlines.name')
```

Is there a way to order by the second association?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you join on the same table twice, using different foreign keys, ActiveRecord goes ahead and aliases all but the first table for you. So while you can reference the `flying_airline` relation with `airlines` in SQL, this won't work for the rest.

The alias created is the pluralized name of the AR relation you are joining (`home_airlines`) prepended to the pluralized class name of the table being joined on (`route_pairs`). So in this case, the alias would be `home_airlines_route_pairs`.

```
RoutePair.joins(:flying_airline, :home_airline).order('home_airlines_route_pairs.name')
```

To order by both associations:

```
RoutePair.joins(:flying_airline, :home_airline).order('airlines.name asc, home_airlines_route_pairs.name asc')
```

To see the SQL that ActiveRecord converts your code into, you can always run `.to_sql` on your query!

```
RoutePair.joins(:flying_airline, :home_airline).to_sql
```

Comment: However, it's causing me PG errors in my spec. `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "home_airlines_commission_rates"` @xml-slayer

Comment: Where did `commission_rates` come from?

Comment: sorry thats `home_airlines_route_pairs`

Comment: Do you know of any documentation for this? Thanks! @xml-slayer

Comment: Not that I've found, I actually just stumbled across this myself earlier this week and [wrote a gist](https://gist.github.com/jmwelch/ed8a008b7ab7630fae7972c1601f3eab) about it

Comment: The PG error was cos I was using in in a module that was used across different models. My bad.